# UIAlertView not showing correctly in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode

In iphone app i am using alertview to check the if textbox values is empty then it should show alert other wise move to next screen but when i also enter the values again alert view is shows i don't know what is the problem

It always shows if true if i also enter value then also

```
   -(IBAction)buttonClick{
   if (monthTextField.text=@"") {

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please enter values first" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];


}


 else if (motionSicknessTextField.text=@"") {

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please enter values first" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];


}


else if (prescriptionTextField.text=@"") {

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please enter values first" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];


}


else if (otherMeansTextField.text=@"") {

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please enter values first" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];


}
else if (cereniaTextField.text=@"") {

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please enter values first" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];


}
else if (costToClientTextField.text=@"") {

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please enter values first" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];


}

else if (clinicMarkup.text=@"") {

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please enter values first" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];


}
   else{    

GraphsViewController*targetController=[[GraphsViewController alloc]init];

NSString*dogswithMotionSickness=motionSicknessTextField.text;
NSString*valueOne=cereniaTextField.text;
NSString*valueTwo=prescriptionTextField.text;
NSString*valueThree=otherMeansTextField.text;
NSString*valueFour=overtheCounterTextField.text;
cerenia=cereniaTextField.text;


NSString*costToClient=costToClientTextField.text;
NSString*clinicalMarkup=clinicMarkup.text;
perMonth=monthTextField.text;


targetController.perMonth=perMonth;
targetController.dogswithMotionSickness=dogswithMotionSickness;

targetController.valueOne=valueOne;
targetController.valueTwo=valueTwo;
targetController.valueThree=valueThree;
targetController.valueFour=valueFour;
targetController.cerenia=cerenia;
targetController.costToClient=costToClient;

targetController.clinicalMarkup=clinicalMarkup;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:targetController animated:YES];

  }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check empty strings, use :

```
if([monthTextField.text isEqualToString:@""])
```

OR

```
if(monthTextField.text.length > 0)
```

Comment: and also use [monthTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] , to ignore white space or newline characters

Comment: This comment is valid because if you have space in your string this condition will be false and logic will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I define these two macros in my AppName-Prefix.pch file

```
#define IS_EMPTY_STRING(str) (!(str) || ![(str) isKindOfClass:NSString.class] || [(str) length] == 0)
#define IS_POPULATED_STRING(str) ((str) && [(str) isKindOfClass:NSString.class] && [(str) length] > 0)
```

This way I can check for both empty strings and nil string objects.

```
IS_EMPTY_STRING(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

also use

```
if ([motionSicknessTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [motionSicknessTextField.text isEqualTo:nil])
```

it is filter with nil and also blank object or value of textField

Comment: its ok dude...but most of time if textfield is not alloc if textfield is custom then this type of condition is very useful..so i put this condition.. :)